# Syntax Error line 0, col 84: Error: Expected end of string, got 'f9f03b9a61c46db91ed492c862a3083'

Tags: doctrine, sql-update, symfony-3.4

I have read a lot of answers for question like this, but no one is correct.
whats wrong in my method?

```
public function updateFileVersion($hash, $date, $size, $fileId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('versions_file');
        $qb->update()
        ->set('versions_file.hash', $hash)
        ->set('versions_file.DateModify', $date)
        ->set('versions_file.checksumSize', $size)
        ->where('versions_file.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $fileId)->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here. I shouldn't have used a second argument

->set('versions_file.hash', $hash)
All I needed was:

->set('versions_file.hash', ':hash')->setParameter(':hash',$hash)
That hasn't in documentation but I hope that it will help somebody in future.